# Could not find or load main class in cmd terminal due to have JSoup

Tags: java, cmd, jsoup

I have made my program with Jsoup where i set the jar file in my intellij.

I have followed the instruction on how to compile java when you need external jar file in cmd by using

```
javac -cp C:\Users\Gagak\IdeaProjects\Java\src\jsoup-1.11.3.jar ClanWarsHistory.java
```

and the compile is working perfectly.

However when i do

```
java -cp C:\Users\Gagak\IdeaProjects\Java\src\jsoup-1.11.3.jar ClanWarsHistory
```

i got this as the output

```
Error: Could not find or load main class ClanWarsHistory
```

This is my import list on my code

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.*;

import static java.util.Map.Entry.comparingByValue;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;
```

I am hoping that i could run my program on my command prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to set the current directory in the classpath

as

> The default class path is the current directory. Setting the CLASSPATH variable or using the -classpath command-line option overrides that default, so if you want to include the current directory in the search path, you must include "." in the new settings.

so something like

```
java -cp .;C:\Users\Gagak\IdeaProjects\Java\src\jsoup-1.11.3.jar ClanWarsHistory
```

should work

Comment: It works, thanks for the help. I will mark this as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use the below command to run your program, need to add current directory in the classpath

```
java -cp .;C:\Users\Gagak\IdeaProjects\Java\src\jsoup-1.11.3.jar ClanWarsHistory
```